# OkHttp3 HTTP GET Request

Tags: java, android, okhttp, http-get

Looking for insight on OkHttp3 to send a simple HTTP GET request to send to a device connected to the network. All the request will do is make the device turn on an alarm for a predetermined amount of time specified while setting up the device ("192.168.1.100/api/relay/1/on/") it cuts itself off after 5 seconds.

I don't have any code as I've deleted it all out of beginners frustration.

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java